# Simple HTML forms Vs Django forms in django (Select in django forms not updating on refresh)

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a drop down list of trainers. I am using this get the html form.

```
class AssignTrainerForm(forms.Form):
    TRAINER = []
    for use in User.objects.filter(Q(role='trainer') & Q(is_active=True)):
        opt = use.username + ' (' + use.first_name + ' ' + use.last_name + ')'
        TRAINER.append((opt, opt))
    trainer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=TRAINER, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

Problem is I have also a functionality of delete trainer or add trainer. If I delete or Add trainer, drop down is not updating when I refresh the page. I have to restart the server.

But If I use simple HTML code (No django form) in html template like:

```
<select class="form-control" name="trainer">
      {% for trainer in trainers %}
      <option>{{ trainer.username }} ({{ trainer.first_name }}
       {{ trainer.last_name }})</option>
       {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

this is giving expected result because on refresh list is coming from DB.

Is there anyway I use django forms and get refreshed data every time I refresh page,

Comment: If you commit your updates to your db then on refresh your changes should be shown.

Comment: I have checked. add/delete is working fine and updating the DB accordingly. but form is not changing. Same thing happens when I write something outside of particular view function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining and executing the User/TRAINER query on first load of the `AssignTrainerForm` class (at start-up of the Django app). Because it is a class attribute, it is only executed once when the class is first parsed and will not be updated until the python process is started again

You can just use a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField), pass the queryset of users and everything will be handled for you. Including updating the choices when changes are made

```
trainer = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    User.objects.filter(Q(role='trainer') & Q(is_active=True)),
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
)
```

EDIT:

To change the label used for each instance in a `ModelChoiceField` you can define your own field and override the `label_from_instance` method

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class UserChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, user):
        return f'{user.first_name} {user.last_name}'

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    trainer = UserChoiceField(
        User.objects.filter(Q(role='trainer') & Q(is_active=True)),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
```

Comment: In options it's showing like object (1), I want name of object. I have tried (queryset=..., to_field_name="name") but it's only change values not the option in drop down.

Comment: By default, `ModelChoiceField`s will use the model/objects `__str__` method which for the User model should be the username